# Python: deployment using fabric library not working - ERROR: unknown command "deploy:3.6.3"

Tags: python, fabric

I have the following fabfile.py implementation that I have used to install the previous version (3.6.2) of my application:

```
from fabric.api import local, run, cd, env, lcd
from fabric.contrib.project import upload_project

git_source = 'git@bitbucket.org:somegitsource'
test_git = False
# Temporary folder defined relative to folder containing this script
temp_folder = '../temp'

def production():
    env.user = 'mywebapp'
    env.hosts = ['aHost']
    env.config = {
        'home': '/home/myDir'
    }

production()


def deploy(version):

    # go to correct location
    with cd(env.config['home']):
        run('mkdir {}'.format(version))
        with cd(version):

            # run and activate virtualenv
            run('virtualenv ve')
            run('. ve/bin/activate')

            checkout(version, test=test_git)

            run('rm -f production')
            with cd('code'):
                pass
                # run("./manage.py sitetree_resync_apps")
                # run("./manage.py migrate")

        run('ln -s {} production'.format(version))
        # sudo /home/myDir/bin/restart-server


def checkout(version):

    local('mkdir {}'.format(temp_folder))
    with lcd(temp_folder):
        # Checkout latest code to temp folder
        local('git clone --branch {0} {1} --depth 1 code'.format(version, git_source))
        # local("gulp")
        upload_project(remote_dir='.')
```

after settings some environment variables the script defines a function called deploy.

The script stopped working. If I invoke it

> fab deploy:3.6.3

I get the error:

> ERROR: unknown command "deploy:3.6.3"

I have read the Fabric documentation but I cannot understand what I am doing wrongly

Answer (score 0):

Since you are declaring a function that you are calling (`production`), Fabric doesn't know which function is a task and which one isn't

You should first import the `task` decorator from `fabric.api`, and then wrap the `deploy` function with this decorator